# Chrome console giving me line number from start of <script> and not top

Tags: console, google-chrome-devtools, line-numbers

This has been bugging me for a while.  At some point my Chrome console started logging the line number from the start of my JS `<script>` tag and not from the top of the file.  I think I might have changed something as it was doing the opposite some time ago.

In this example, Chrome is spitting out 'hello' as being on line 20 (270-250=20), not 270 as it was.

```
<html> - line 1
...
<script> - line 250
...
console.log('hello') - line 270
```

Unfortunately it has made this highly helpful feature basically useless.  Has anybody experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

Please try updating your Chrome version. It works fine for me at least on Chrome 22 and later... If it still fails for you, you can file a new bug at http://new.crbug.com, its summary starting with "DevTools:". Also, providing a publicly available test case will drastically reduce the bug triage and investigation time (remember, a simplistic case worked for me on Chrome 22!)

Comment: Updating to Chrome 22 didn't help unfortunately.  I submitted a bug report through chrome://chrome/help/ and http://new.crbug.com/.  How should I provide a test case for this problem?

Comment: You can either attach a test case to the bug or specify a link to a publicly accessible test case there. Posting the crbug id here is also a good idea, to link this post with the bug.

Comment: The only thing I can think to do would be to give someone remote access to my computer.  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150784

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question so I don't know if it will help but I found this while trying to solve another Chrome Devtools bug.

I encountered this problem recently and it seems that something(corruption?) can happen to the file that prevents Chrome from properly reading line breaks. In my case it was reporting that all console.log()'s were coming from line:1. After pulling my hair out for some time the only solution I found is to rename the offending file, create a new file with the original file name, and then paste all the code into the new file. console.log() should now report from the correct line numbers.